# Linux script is not running in crontab where as it's run manually ok

Tags: linux

I have a Script which  check a size of a log file. if the log file size are( appending logs) increase then it's do nothing but if it is not increasing then it say some thing or sms me .

Logic is: this file is run on crontab in every 3 minute for every day 08 am to 10 pm.

1) in night 00 hrs msize.txt file will 00
2) in morning 08 hrs size variable reads data from msize.txt file and compare with size2 variable if size2 is less than or equal to size then i have do SMS.
size2 variable fetch file size of that log file in script..
and after finish size2 variable value is written in msize.txt file....

What happen when i run this script in manually it ok msize.txt is modify but in crontab msize.txt is not modify or create....

Script is:-----

```
dt=`date +%H`


if [ $dt -eq 00 ]
then
echo $dt > msize.txt
fi

size=`cat msize.txt`
#echo $size
size2=`du /pretupsvar/pretups_smsrlogs/messageSentLog.log| awk '{print $1}'`
name=`uname -n`

if [ $size2 -le $size ]
 then
Do Somthing



#echo "not happen"
fi

echo $size2 > msize.txt
```

---

Please help me ASAP

Comment: Can you post the corresponding crontab line?

Answer (score 1):

The script assumes that `msize.txt` is in the current working directory. When you run the script by hand, presumably the current working directory is where that file is located. When the script is run from cron, though, the working directory is your home directory. You need to use a full path for that file, or a `cd` command in the script to set the working directory appropriately.

Comment: To show gratitude on SO it's customary to upvote helpful answers and "accept" the correct answer...

Answer (score 0):

If you only run this script from crontab between 08:00 and 22:00 the code in:

```
if [ $dt -eq 00 ]
then
echo $dt > msize.txt
fi
```

won't ever be run?